# Create a custom login screen GUI for linux

Tags: c, linux, user-interface

I would like to customize the login screen in a Linux OS. Not just the bacground image, but everything from buttons to textboxes, even the login method (so not a username + password, but something of my own).

The flavor of Linux doesn't really matter, it only needs to have a graphical interface. I have some experience with Ubuntu though.

However, this would be my first time developing something for Linux -- I have developed applications for Windows before, mostly in C# -- but I am up to the challange to learn something new. So please try to be a bit easier on me, me being something of a noob at the moment.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading about what questions are considered off-topic here on SO. Thanks!

Comment: I can't really understand why would this question be considered off-topic. E.g. based on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254394/5015755) discussion, my question seems to be on-topic. But please explain it to me if I am wrong!

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of resources, books, tutorials and so on are generally considered off-topic.

Comment: As I see it, I am just trying to solve a specific task/problem, and _of course_ it will include external resources to solve.

Comment: I edited the question, it might have been misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "login screen" shown on GNU/Linux systems to login to a graphical session is part of the desktop environment you are using. Various alternatives exist for the zoo of alternative environments out there. Examples are `kdm` as offered by the KDE desktop environment, `gdm` as offered by Gnome, `xdm`, `wdm`, many others exist. Start by reading the [wikipedia article about `kdm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Display_Manager) to get an impression.

You'd have to implement a replacement for that part which serves the same purpose, if the existing options to configure it are not enough. So best probably is to start reading about those. That should give you an impression about the requirements.

Roughly explained you have to create an executable that can be executed by the system and configure that as "desktop manager" in the systems configuration. The exact location of that configuration again depends on the distribution, but the general approach always is the same.

The logic of such a program has to somehow answer the question of whether a user is allowed to login to the system by whatever means chosen. Typically this is done by using `PAM` in background ("Pluggable authentication modules"). Maybe start by reading an [introduction to `PAM`](http://aplawrence.com/Basics/understandingpam.html) to gain insight into how things work, which may be a bit confusing at first glance due to its endless flexibility. That framework is used on modern unixoid systems to separate the requirements for that logic from the actual implementation. So you really want to learn about how `PAM` works too. It is an unbelievable flexible framework where already endless strategies exist, so countless adapters for all sorts of existing authorities like databases, LDAP servers, simple file based authorities, IMAP servers, you name it: everything you can imagine. So chances are that you do not have to implement anything, but just can pick something implemented by someone else and configure / tailor it to your needs.

The logic itself does not have to be complex, it just has to answer that simple question in an clear way: is the user who requests access granted or not. For that it will (or will not) have to consult some existing authority. How exactly that works obviously is completely up to you. The real difficult thing probably is to access and control the graphics hardware *without* having a running graphical desktop environment to build on (since that is only started afterwards). So you probably have to deal with some hardware abstraction layer. Which again means that you probably want to be using some language like `C` or `C++` for that job, scripting languages are less well suited for such job, also because they introduce all sorts of additional requirements of what has to be installed on a system which becomes unusable if some element inside that chain of utilities break due to the lack of a login screen :-)